# Magento Installation Error: SQL max_allowed_packet value

Tags: magento2, sql

I am trying to install Magento 2.3.0 CE with Sample data, but the installer fails because my hosting have the **max_allowed_packet** set to **16M.**
In this post of someone with the same problem the issue is solved, setting that variable at **256M.**

> https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Warning-Error-while-sending-QUERY-packet/td-p/88511

But my hosting refuses to change that setting, arguing that is a system wide parameter in a shared hosting with another customers. And because of this, i am stuck.
Is there any way to install Magento 2.3.0 CE in a SQL server with the max_allowed_packet set to 16M?
I have also read somewhere that the recomended setting for magento is 16M, and i suspect that is the Sample Data is the responsible of this error.
Thank you very much.